# Basic assembly question

Tags: c, assembly

```
mov     r8, FlushCounts[r14]
```

Can some one explain me what the FlushCounts[r14] is used for ? Does this mean r14 = &FlushCounts and r8 = FlushCounts ? Why is it done like this ?

Comment: Which CPU are you writing assembly for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means copy 64 bits from address `FlushCount + r14` to r8. Offset in `r14` register is in bytes.

Answer (score 1):

This instruction is basically `r8 = *(FlushCounts+r14)`.

Comment: This is the origin of array notation, it allows you to specify an offset without having to specify address or do pointer arithmetic. In a way it abstracts the pointer to the concept of an array variable